# Does a Type represent a numeric value C#

Tags: c#, types

I am wondering if there is a system function which will tell me if a type represents a numeric value (for a custom TypeConverter). Sure checking for each type known type works ok, but I don't really like it.

```
        if (destinationType == typeof( int))
            return true;

        if (destinationType == typeof( Int16))
            return true;

        if (destinationType == typeof( Int32))
            return true 
        ...
        if (destinationType == typeof( float))
            return true;
        ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I definitely remember be asked and answered, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: it get asked alot... it would be a ncie feature that doesn't exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437882/c-equivalent-of-nan-or-isnumeric

Comment: I figured it might be a reasonably common question and somehow suspected that it wouldn't exist.
@xcud - I am looking to see if the type represents a number rather than if a string does.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375026/c-numeric-base-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Linq ExpressionNode (internal class) IsNumeric method, it is basically testing against every type.

```
if (!IsFloat(type))
{
    return IsInteger(type);
}
return true;
```

And the two function are testing against the primitive type, like

```
internal static bool IsInteger(StorageType type)
{
    if ((((type != StorageType.Int16) && (type != StorageType.Int32)) && ((type != StorageType.Int64) && (type != StorageType.UInt16))) && (((type != StorageType.UInt32) && (type != StorageType.UInt64)) && (type != StorageType.SByte)))
    {
        return (type == StorageType.Byte);
    }
    return true;
}
```

StorageType is a Linq specific class, but you get the idea: just test against every type.

It is the easiest way to know if the value is a numeric type.

Comment: I figured that it would come down to individual testing of types in the end :(