# Can I Create a Generic Method for Sum In C#

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generics - where T is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267902/generics-where-t-is-a-number)

I have created a generic method for maximum and I use `IComparable` interface

Does anybody know how can I create a generic method for Sum? Which interface is useful in this method?

Here is my code for GetMax:

```
public static T GetMax<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable
    {
        T min = array[0];

        foreach (T item in array)
        {
            if (min.CompareTo(item) < 0)
            {
                min = item;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: @mikez No, of course. Look at closer.

Answer (score 8):

this operation already exists `Linq.Sum()`

```
var sum = new List<int>{1,2,3}.Sum();
```

Comment: Only other thing to add is you have to add "using System.Linq;" at the top of your class.

Comment: Note that LINQ provides multiple overloads of `Sum` for different types. If you have an IEnumerable<T> and don't know T (because the method is generic), then you can't use this method.

Comment: But how would you describe the behaviour of complex objects here?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't create one generic method for all types. But you can use `LINQ` extension method `Sum` for some types: `decimal`, `double`, `int`, `long`, ...
See more types here: [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb345537.aspx).

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int sum1 = array1.Sum();
```

For your own types you can create and implement interface `ISummable`:

```
interface ISummable<T>
{
   T Add(T a, T b);
}
```

Then your generic method will be similar to this one:

```
T Sum<T>(T a, T b) where T:ISummable<T>
{
    return a.Add(a,b);
}
```

See more information here: [Making generics add up](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84413/making-generics-add-up/).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to write a generic method `Sum` like this:

```
static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) where T : ??
{
    T result = 0;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        result = result + value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately there is no constraint that you could put in place of `??` to make this work.

The data types built into .NET implement certain interfaces. For example, [**int**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) implements IComparable, IFormattable,    IConvertible, IComparable<int>, and IEquatable<int>. None of these provide an `Add` method (or `+` operator) that would allow you to implement a `Sum` method. And you cannot add interface implementation to existing types.

What you can do, is pass a an object to the `Sum` method that knows how to add two values of the generic type:

```
static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, IAdder<T> adder)
{
    T result = adder.Zero;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        result = adder.Add(result, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

with

```
interface IAdder<T>
{
    T Zero { get; }

    T Add(T a, T b);
}
```

and

```
class Int32Adder : IAdder<Int32>
{
    public static readonly Instance = new Int32Adder();

    public int Zero { get { return 0; } }

    public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

Comment: your solution has potential bug - class without zero-state will be miscalculation wrong, realization have to be ugly, with switch condition

Comment: if (values.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(); var result = values.GetValue(); for (var i = 1; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        result = adder.Add(result, values[i]);
    }
    return result; //need add GetValue to interface, Linq.First() is not pass