# How to make an extension method for all integral types?

Tags: c#

I've written a static extension method that acts on an `int`, but I'd like to make it more robust to act on any [integral value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx), such as `ushort` or `char`. Is there any way to do this, short of code duplication?

Right now my method signature looks something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T MyCoolMethod<T>(this int value) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can I swap out `int` for some common interface, or do something else with generics to get it so this extension method can apply to any integral type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267902/generics-where-t-is-a-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348594/is-there-a-c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-real-number-types, try searching.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer, but it closed. Try modifying your method signature to `public static T MyCoolMethod<T>(this T value) where T : struct, IConvertible` but you can't constrain to integral types, it will appear on any type that is both a struct and IConvertible.

Comment: @SoaperGEM, @Ron : You can probably pin it down slightly tighter than that: something like `where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>`, although it's still far from perfect.

Comment: The T type is the output type, not the input, which is actually getting cast to an enum. So I need the integral input type and the enum output types to be different.

Comment: @LukeH Yes, it gets you closer, but still not quite there. I keep flopping back and forth between *"It would have been nice to have"* and *"I can't imagine why you'd want that"*.

Comment: @SoaperGEM Thats easy too... `public static T MyCoolMethod<T,U>(this U value) where U ...` you can have multiple generics.

Comment: @RonBeyer but how do you format the `where` part when you have different constraints for the two generics? Is there something like an `and` keyword?

Comment: No, you just repeat the "where" part, like `Method<T,U>(this U value) where T : struct, IConvertible where U : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. You should write some base method and call it from every implementation which bases on the specific type.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this at compile time; this is because there's no generic constraint for integral types. At runtime, however, you could check whether [`typeof(T).IsPrimitive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx) and throw and error otherwise.

If your method works against a constraint of `struct`, you should consider leaving it at that.