# Implement operator overrides / Equatable<T> for all primitive number datatypes at once?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I want to implement my own CustomNumber class, and have it comparable to all other primitive number datatypes (int, long, double, float, etc.) using the relational operators.

Is there a way to do that for all of them at once, or do I really have to override the ==, !=, >, <, >= and <= operators aswell as the Equals(T other) method for each single integral datatype?

I think I know how operator overloading works in general, but it feels like there must be some kind of shortcut in order to make my CustomNumber comparable to all primitive number datatypes using relational operators, instead of having to overload each of those 6 operators for each single datatype, which might quickly add up to about 100 overload definitions.

Comment: `How did you come to that conclusion?` Because I can't imagine that Microsoft did override all of those operators for each other type in each of the data type files. That would take around 100 operator overrides per datatype, so you'd end up with like 1000 operator overrides just to compare primitive number datatypes? Also coming from Java I know that there is a Number class that all number datatypes inherit from. Hopefully there is something like a number superclass in C# too that will do most of the operator work for me?

Comment: Side note: `public static bool operator == (MyType x, double c)…` with `public static bool operator == (double c, MyType x)...` will cover all regular numeric types (except `decimal` which is special and not really "numeric") unless you need to avoid automatic conversions  (You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types for some more inspirations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut *per se*, you have to implement all the operators and functionality for all the types you want to support, it can't read your mind.

Check out the `decimal` [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs).

For your sanity you will notice not everything needs to be overridden, this is done by the implementation of implicit operators:

```
public static implicit operator Decimal(byte value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static implicit operator Decimal(sbyte value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static implicit operator Decimal(short value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static implicit operator Decimal(ushort value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static implicit operator Decimal(char value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static implicit operator Decimal(int value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static implicit operator Decimal(uint value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static implicit operator Decimal(long value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static implicit operator Decimal(ulong value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}


public static explicit operator Decimal(float value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static explicit operator Decimal(double value)
{
   return new Decimal(value);
}

public static explicit operator byte(Decimal value)
{
   return ToByte(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static explicit operator sbyte(Decimal value)
{
   return ToSByte(value);
}

public static explicit operator char(Decimal value)
{
   UInt16 temp;
   try
   {
      temp = ToUInt16(value);
   }
   catch (OverflowException e)
   {
      throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Char"), e);
   }
   return (char)temp;
}

public static explicit operator short(Decimal value)
{
   return ToInt16(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static explicit operator ushort(Decimal value)
{
   return ToUInt16(value);
}

public static explicit operator int(Decimal value)
{
   return ToInt32(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static explicit operator uint(Decimal value)
{
   return ToUInt32(value);
}

public static explicit operator long(Decimal value)
{
   return ToInt64(value);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static explicit operator ulong(Decimal value)
{
   return ToUInt64(value);
}

public static explicit operator float(Decimal value)
{
   return ToSingle(value);
}

public static explicit operator double(Decimal value)
{
   return ToDouble(value);
}

public static Decimal operator +(Decimal d)
{
   return d;
}

public static Decimal operator -(Decimal d)
{
   return Negate(d);
}

public static Decimal operator ++(Decimal d)
{
   return Add(d, One);
}

public static Decimal operator --(Decimal d)
{
   return Subtract(d, One);
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static Decimal operator +(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   FCallAddSub(ref d1, ref d2, DECIMAL_ADD);
   return d1;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static Decimal operator -(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   FCallAddSub(ref d1, ref d2, DECIMAL_NEG);
   return d1;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static Decimal operator *(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   FCallMultiply(ref d1, ref d2);
   return d1;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static Decimal operator /(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   FCallDivide(ref d1, ref d2);
   return d1;
}

public static Decimal operator %(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return Remainder(d1, d2);
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator ==(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) == 0;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator !=(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) != 0;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator <(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) < 0;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator <=(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) <= 0;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator >(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) > 0;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator >=(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
{
   return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like they only override the `==` operator (and all others) for `Decimal` though. How come then that I can also do this: `Decimal x = 4; int y = 4; if (x == y) { }` when the == operator is never overridden for the parameters `Decimal d1, int d2`? Similarly I can do stuff like `if (5.0 == 5) { }` even though technically those are different types too? (double, int)

Comment: @user2015253 you are right, however you will need implicit operators for them, i suggest looking up what explicit and implicit operators do

Comment: Ah that might actually hint me into the right direction now. I will research about those keywords. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

As partial shortcut you can limit your overrides to `double` which cover all regular "numeric" types at cost of compiler inserted cast. Always comparing to `double` is dangerous for larger integer values (`int` and smaller types will be precise always).

```
class MyType 
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
    public static bool operator == (MyType x, double c)
    {
       // write some real code here - this one does not have a value to compare to. 
       return c > 42; 
    }

    // you need all several overrides for each operator to behave in expected way
    // so calling the same one (a == b)
    // from a != b, b != a, b == a is a way to keep them consistent
    public static bool operator == (double c, MyType x)
    {
        return (x == c);
    }

    public static bool operator != (double c, MyType x)
    {
        return !(c == x);   
    }

    public static bool operator != (MyType x, double c)
    {
        return !(x == c);
    }
}
```

Notes

- C#/ .NET do not have built in concept of "numeric" type - this is something people ask often enough (i.e. [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types), [Generics - where T is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267902/generics-where-t-is-a-number)).
- don't forget to implement `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable`, `IComparable<T>`...
- consider if it is actually useful for your "numbers" to be able to freely mix with other types -  especially for comparison with imprecise `float`/`double` which already painful enough.