# Can we have a generic function with return type same as input parameter type?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-function

Can we have a generic function with return type same as return type of a anonymous function which is a parameter of the first function ?

As shown below ?

```
  public T Read(List<int> autIds, Func<DataSet, T> executeFn)
    {

    }
```

I am getting "Cant resolve T" message - Is this something doable?

Comment: `...Read<T>(...`. Feel free to close as typographical error, or maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745815/in-c-what-is-t-after-a-method-declaration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you need to define `T`:

```
public T Read<T>(List<int> autIds, Func<DataSet, T> executeFn)
```