# Generic C# Code and the Plus Operator

Tags: c#, generics, math

I'm writing a class that does essentially the same type of calculation for each of the primitive numeric types in C#.  Though the real calculation is more complex, think of it as a method to compute the average of a number of values, e.g.

```
class Calc
{
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public int Total { get; private set; }
    public int Average { get { return Count / Total; } }
    public int AddDataPoint(int data)
    {
        Total += data;
        Count++;
    }
}
```

Now to support that same operation for double, float and perhaps other classes that define operator + and operator /, my first thought was to simply use generics:

```
class Calc<T>
{
    public T Count { get; private set; }
    public T Total { get; private set; }
    public T Average { get { return Count / Total; } }
    public T AddDataPoint(T data)
    {
        Total += data;
        Count++;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately C# is unable to determine whether T supports operators + and / so does not compile the above snippet.  My next thought was to constrain T to types that support those operators, but my initial research indicates this cannot be done.

It's certainly possible to box each of the types I want to support in a class that implements a custom interface e.g. IMath and restrict T to that, but this code will be called a great number of times and I want to avoid boxing overhead.

Is there an elegant and efficient way to solve this without code duplication?

Comment: Can't you just use LINQ? Sum and Average are supported on IEnumerable.

Comment: Check out this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-generic-constraint-for-only-integers

Comment: @Mathias: No, I used this as a simplified example of the actual calculation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using Expressions, an approach outlined by Marc Gravell that I found by following links off of spinon's comment.

https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Comment: Just make sure you cache the delegates and re-use them ;p

Comment: Note also that MiscUtils has a pre-built `Operator` class that provides all the necessary utility methods you are likely to need.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, I implemented your comment ;-)

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote 3+ years later? A reason for downvoting a significantly upvoted answer would be helpful.

Comment: This is a great solution by Marc Gravell

Comment: Looks like the site doesn't work anymore. /cc @MarcGravell

Comment: @tukaef moved: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Answer (score 6):

(excuse me if I post it today, but I was looking for a place where to put this piece of code, and this question seemed to be perfect)

As an extension on the Gravell's article:

```
public static class Add<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Do;

    static Add()
    {
        var par1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var par2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var add = Expression.Add(par1, par2);

        Do = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(add, par1, par2).Compile();
    }
}
```

You use it like:

```
int sum = Add<int>.Do(x, y);
```

The advantage is that we use the type system of .NET for safekeeping the various "variants" of `Add` and creating new ones if necessary. So the first time you call `Add<int>.Do(...)` the `Expression` will be built, but if you call it a second time, the `Add<int>` will already be fully initialized.

On some simple benchmark, it's 2x slower than direct addition. I think it's very good. Ah... it's compatible with objects that redefine the `operator+`. Clearly building the other operations is easy.

**Addition from Meirion Hughes**

Method can be extended with meta-coding so you can handle cases of `T1` *operation* `T2`. For instance, here if `T1` is a number, then it needs to be converted to `T2 == double` first before the `operator *` then converts it back. Whereas when `T1` is `Foo` and `Foo` has operator to multiply with a `T2 == double` you can omit the conversion. The `try`, `catch` is necessary because it is the easiest way to check if the `T operator *(T, double)` is present.

```
public static class Scale<T>
{
    public static Func<T, double, T> Do { get; private set; }

    static Scale()
    {
        var par1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var par2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double));

        try
        {
            Do = Expression
                .Lambda<Func<T, double, T>>(
                    Expression.Multiply(par1, par2),
                    par1, par2)
                .Compile();
        }
        catch
        {
            Do = Expression
                .Lambda<Func<T, double, T>>(
                    Expression.Convert(
                        Expression.Multiply(
                            Expression.Convert(par1, typeof (double)),
                            par2),
                        typeof(T)),
                    par1, par2)
                .Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Meirion I don't like very much what you did (adding by editing)... But the code was neat. I've re-edited a little and changed a little the explanation

Comment: yeah I know, sorry. I thought it would be useful (it was for me), and I was about to add it as separate answer, but this thread is locked and the other thread would be off-topic. :/

Comment: @MeirionHughes Just the next time, put your name on the added piece of text, like I did *Addition from Meirion Hughes*, so it is clear what is from the author 1 and what is from the author 2

Answer (score 2):

There is an approach using dynamic in C# 4.0, it is not perfect obviously but it can bring a new light to the matter.

Details are [in this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806200048/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/lucabol/archive/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0.aspx)

Comment: The trouble with 'dynamic' is that it introduces another level of indirection.  I'm performing a large number of complex calculations and suspect (but don't know, to be honest) that the indirection will have a measurable impact on overall app performance.

Answer (score 1):

I found another interesting approach, which is easier to code and debug than the expression tree solution I originally used:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericnumerics.aspx

This solution uses generic type constraints in an interesting way to ensure all required operations are supported, but without introducing any boxing or virtual method calls.