# List/array of values with multiple different types

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have need to store multiple values in list or array for a moment. These values are multiple types like string, int, datetime etc.

I have two options:

Options 1:

Declare an array with type of object like this:

```
object[] values;
```

Option 2:

Declare array for interface and implement own classes for each type to hold.

```
interface IType
{
}

IType[] values;

class StringValue : IType
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }  // not declared in interface!
}

class IntValue : IType
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }  // not declared in interface!
}
```

**Question:**

What are performance benefit and/or impact for each implementation options? As far as I know (or quessing), boxinq has own performance impact when using `object[]`.

What about option two? At least using `StringValue` or `IntValue` property needs more code, first type must be determined, `IType` must be casted to StringValue or IntValue etc...

Is there so big impact to performance using `object[]` that I really should think about something like options 2?

Comment: Before worrying about performance, EVER, just implement and write your code, and TEST TEST TEST, and see if performance is an issue, then you can optimize, **if necessary**

Comment: Of course! I already implemented options 1 and because I know (not metered!) there is going to be some issues I just think how can I make my code better. Maybe question is more to ask what might be better than options 1 ....

Comment: Asking for "better" is not going to help - you need to clarify better in what sense.

Comment: Ok forget that "better" ... just compare those two options. Options 1 just needs same casting (which is known to be slow), option 2 needs more code around and more if/switch blocks etc ... so is this complex code going to eat all performace benefit...?

Comment: What are you going to do with each of those string, int, and datetime values?  Are you just going to print them to the screen, are you going to have some method somewhere that is checking the type in a big switch and casting them back to int/string/datetime?  Without knowing how these objects are to be used we can't know if this is appropriate or if there is a better option.\

Comment: @Servy - that's the same thing that jumped out at me. Concern over performance suggests that something is going to be *done* with these objects based on type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `IntValue` you propose essentially boxes an integer... it encapsulates it in an object to that it can participate in an object[].  I would expect no performance *improvement* with that scenario, and depending on your implementation, it could be worse than compiler-implemented boxing.

Having said that, I agree with the commenters that your efforts are probably better focused improving other areas of your code.  There are very few scenarios where the boxing overhead will be the most important area of attention.

I did encounter a scenario (working with many numbers that could be int, float, or double) where the boxing mattered to user experience.  I solved that [using expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039694/generic-c-sharp-code-and-the-plus-operator/8812486#8812486).

Comment: The one advantage of that interface model is that you ensure the array can only have `ints`, `strings`, `datetimes`, or other classes that implement the interface (which if it's internal, will be a known finite amount).  If you use `object` it really can be anything.

Comment: True, but then again, the interface has one member per type.  It's not really an interface in the normal sense (one interface to multiple implementations).  One may as well derive from a common base type to get that benefit.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I also found this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/808ad927-385f-49c9-aace-256eefe659d7

Comment: Servy: implementation is internal in assembly so I know all aspects of code, no need to expose them outside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much performance impact. The reflection used to find the type of the object might slow it down a little bit if you use object[] _objects. The .GetType() function.