# Generics Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)
>   [Implementing arithmetic in generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951392/implementing-arithmetic-in-generics)

I wrote Generics class,but i am having issue as described in title.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 2;
            int c = 3;

            dynamic obj = new Gen<int>();
            obj.TestLine1(ref a, ref b);
            obj = new Gen<string>();
            obj.TestLine2(ref a, ref b, ref c);
            System.Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

public class Gen<T>
    {
        public void TestLine1(ref T a, ref T b)
        {
            T temp;
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        public void TestLine2(ref T a, ref T b, ref T c)
        {
            T temp;
            temp = a;
            a = a + b;
            b = a + c;
            c = a + b;
        }
    }
```

Inside at method TestLine2(ref T a, ref T b, ref T c) I am getting below issue:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Comment: It is a quite common problem in C#. You can't define a constraint on _T_ to specify "_T_ must implement the + operator"

Comment: You have not bounded `T` to be constrained to `+`able types, so the compiler has no way to know that `+` can be applied to `T`.

Comment: Duplicate of about 10,000 earlier questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bgenerics%5D+arithmetic  Look for an answer written by Marc Gravell, he's solved this nicely

Answer (score 8):

Since `T` can be any type, there is no guarantee that `T` will have a static `+` operator. In C# there's no way to constrain `T` to support static operators like `+`, so you'll have to pass the function to use to combine values of `T` to `TestLine2`:

```
public void TestLine2(ref T a, ref T b, ref T c, Func<T, T, T> op)
{
    T temp;
    temp = a;
    a = op(a, b);
    b = op(a, c);
    c = op(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't know whether `T` implements the + operator. What if you pass `object` as the type parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of T is not known until instantiation, there is no guarantee that the type T will support the + operator.

Comment: True but it is only a diagnose rather than a solution.

Comment: @Wicktor: There was no question and no research effort.  Perhaps an explanation is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I created an instance of your class like this: `var gen = new Gen<Object>()`. Now `T` means `Object` everywhere inside this instance of your class. When you call `TestLine2()`, the method is going to try to add to Objects, something that can't be done in C#.

More broadly, since C# doesn't know ahead of time what type arguments you're going to create a `Gen` object with, it restricts you to only using methods defined for all objects.

It looks to me like you really want `TestLine2` to be a method for consisting strings. Why don't you just make `Gen` a non-generic class and tell it to use `String`s everywhere instead?