# Make a method accept multiple numeric parameters of different type

Tags: c#

Basically i have a specific method which uses double and int  values to figure out a css class i want to set. I'm doing the same in a different place but with int + int there instead.

That spawned the question whether there is a good way to have a one for all solution.

Overloads would have been one way to do it but i would love to not write an overload for all variations of numbers.

So i thought i'd have a look wether there is a number specific interface type i can use as generic type constraint - but i didn't find one (since anything could implement IConvertible?)

Result of int32 decompile :

```
#if GENERICS_WORK
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    , IComparable<Int32>, IEquatable<Int32>
/// , IArithmetic<Int32>
#else
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
#endif
```

Nope, no number interface.

This is what i came up with - which works fine, but also accepts calls on potential non number objects. Any suggestions on how to make the method more restrictive?

```
    public static string GetThresholdColorClass(IConvertible desiredThreshold, IConvertible actualProgress)
    {
        var actual = actualProgress.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var desired = desiredThreshold.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (actual >= desired)
            return "green";
        if (actual <= 0)
            return "red";
        return "yellow";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there isn't anything (see for example [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types)). You can't make a generic class that requires "numbers" as parameters.

What you could do is create only the `double` variant of the methods (there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`, and `double`s can contain all the `int` values)

Technically Gravell wrote some functions to do math with generic types... see https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html , but they are a little "hack"ey :-)

Comment: meh. shame there is no built in way. however implicit casting does the job too here. Also thanks for the reference to that other question. Kind of makes mine a duplicate. Didn't find it while searching though - slightly different words. Now i'll have to look up the T4 solution because that looks rather interesting as well. haha. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreasMüller If you want to test the generic "hack", here there are some lines of code I wrote some years ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/18190731/613130 . You can easily repurpose them for the other operators.