# Is possible to combine Generic Constraint with operator overloading?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, generic-constraints

I wonder if with Generic Constraint (when) it is possible to allow this code ?

And what is the right pattern to do this?

```
public MyClass<T>
{
    public void MyMethod(T a, T b) 
    {
       //some code
       var result = a<b;
      //some code 
    }
}
```

my question is for all operator in general

```
+, -, !, ~, ++, --, *, /, %, &, |, ^, <<, >>, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=
```

Comment: Are you speaking about the proposed C# 8.0 recursive pattern matching or what?

Comment: I don't know nothing about C# and recursive pattern matching, I am using C# 7.2.
But I didnt specify C# version in my version because, I don't really matter about this.

Comment: @xanatos, I guess the question is whether we can cast `T` to some "type that has a `<` operator defined".

Comment: @TetyanaKorogoda I want just to specify in the method that T has an implementation of the <  operator.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove At this point of time (May 2018), the only thing you can do is add a constraint `: IComparable<T>` to the class definition and use the `CompareTo` method instead of the `<`

Comment: @xanatos ok thank you, and what about the others operators?

Comment: @ChristopheDebove For the +,-,*,/,% there is no hope at this point :-), for the == there is `IEquatable<T>`, for the >, >=, <= there is the `IComparable<T>`

Comment: @xanatos good to know :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point of time (May 2018), the only thing you can do is add a constraint to `IComparable<T>` to the class definition and use the `CompareTo` method instead of the `<`.

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public void MyMethod(T a, T b) 
    {
       //some code
       var result = a.CompareTo(b) < 0; // a < b
       //some code 
    }
}
```

This will cover `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` (and technically even the `==`, but it is better to use `IEquatable<T>`), for the `==` you can add a constraint to `IEquatable<T>` to the class definition and use the `Equals` method instead of the `==` (and the `!Equals` instead of the `!=`).

For math/bitwise operators at this point there is no hope. There are always requests for this feature in the C# wishlist, but they always get postponed. In the C# 8.0 this feature won't be present (probably). See the [official list of candidates](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/8). See [Generic C# Code and the Plus Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4039694) for an older question about this. Note that the solutions given won't give errors at compile time if you try to use a non-existing operator, but will give those errors at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about pattern matching actually. `where` (not `when`) in this case means [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).
And no it's not possible to have a constraint on an operator.

You may want to use custom interface instead, adding a constraint on it.

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: ICustomInterface
```

[`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a good candidate for the `>` operator, but it will not fit as far as you want to have operator overloaded.

By the way, F# allows you to have such a constraint — it's called [Member constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) — with use of [Statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters). It allows you to add constraint on any type member or operator. But that's not a CLR feature, it's possible just because of rich type inference system.

Comment: ok I mixed the generic constraints with pattern matching my bad