# Type problems with bytes and shorts

Tags: c#, types

Hey everyone. I have a function that works both with short input values, as with byte input values, here `pixelData` is an array filled with either bytes or shorts.

```
       byte oColor;
        if (pixelData[counter/3] < minValue)
            oColor = 0;
        else if (pixelData[counter/3] > maxValue)
            oColor = 255;
        else
            oColor = (byte)(((pixelData[counter/3] - (WindowLevel - (WindowWidth / 2))) * 255) / WindowWidth);
```

Then I have the following code:

```
bool isShort = ReadIsShort();
if(isShort){
 shortArray = ReadShortArray();
} else {
 byteArray = ByteArray();
}
```

To get either the short or the byte array. However, I cannot use them in function above. Since something like this doesn't work.

```
var pixelData;
if(IsShort)
 pixelData = shortArray;
else
 pixelData = byteArray;
```

Anyone know how I should program this, since this clearly is a design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# is a strongly typed language, every variable must have a well-defined type. Therefore, `pixelData` can only be either a short *or* a byte array. So far there's no design flaw here imo.

I assume, that your computations are more or less performance-critical (since there are pixels involved :)), so I won't repeat the suggestion of using boxing (cast to object[]) or creating Lists or similar things.

Even using generics is not an option, since you cannot give arithemtic type constraints for generic functions (see [this qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-generic-constraint-for-only-integers)) The only solution I can think of is to duplicate the code and write two explicit versions, one for each data type.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I've been thinking of too. I guess it's gonna be duplicate code =(

Comment: Oh and by design flaw, i meant a design flaw by me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try obtaining `object[]` arrays and use this as your final `else`.  I'm not sure I'm crazy about the problem to begin with, though.  Is there any way you can go back and refactor so that there is a consistent data type?

```
oColor = (byte)(((Convert.ToInt16(pixelData[counter / 3]) - (WindowLevel - (WindowWidth / 2))) * 255) / WindowWidth);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, there is absolutly a way I can refactor. But I'm not quite sure how I have to implement it..

Answer (score 0):

You could change `pixelData` to an `object[]` and use

```
if (isShort)
    Array.Copy(shortData, pixelData, shortData.Length);
else
    Array.Copy(byteData, pixelData, byteData.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a type for `pixelData` - one that both a short or byte would convert to, or could contain your array.

Can you change the array of bytes to a List of shorts, since that wouldn't lose any data?  Then you can change your function to just act on one type - something like `List<Short>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a generic method using [Comparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx), but I'm not sure how this would affect performance:

```
void ProcessPixelData<T>(T[] pixelData, T minValue, T maxValue)
{
    // ...

    byte oColor;
    if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(pixelData[counter / 3], minValue) < 0)
        oColor = 0;
    else if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(pixelData[counter / 3], maxValue) > 0)
        oColor = 255;
    else
        oColor = (byte)(((pixelData[counter/3] - (WindowLevel - (WindowWidth / 2))) * 255) / WindowWidth);

    // ...
}
```

Actually, couldn't `ByteArray()` return a `short[]`?  Then you could just work with `pixelData` as a `short[]` for both cases.