# How to compute cumulative product (or sum) of a Series in Deedle (ideally in c# rather than F#)?

Tags: c#, deedle

How to compute the cumulative product (or sum) of a Series in Deedle (ideally in c# rather than F#)? Anything smart with Windowing / Aggregation?

Just a reference, i want to code using deedle the equivalent of this line of code in python/pandas

> curve['equity_curve'] = (1.0+curve['returns']).cumprod()

Thanks a ton

Cheers,
Lamp'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deedle has cummulative sum function built-in (`Stats.expandingSum`), but it does not have expanding multiplication. I think the easiest option is to implement [Scan method for ordinary IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551271/summing-the-previous-values-in-an-ienumerable) and then use it as follows:

```
 var result = input.Observations.Scan
   (KeyValue.Create(-1, 1.0), (acc, kvp) =>
      KeyValue.Create(kvp.Key, acc.Value * kvp.Value)).Skip(1).ToSeries();
```

For completeness, the `Scan` extension method looks something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Scan<T, U>
    (this IEnumerable<T> input, U state, Func<U, T, U> next) {
  yield return state;
  foreach (var item in input) {
    state = next(state, item);
    yield return state;
  }
}
```