# Where constraint for simple types and string

Tags: c#, .net, generic-constraints

I have a generic method that I would like to put a constraint on.

```
public T MyMethod<T>(object obj) where T : ???
```

The constraint is all simple types int, bool etc but I also need to allow string. I there a way of constraining this group?

Comment: Why do you need this? This sounds like a frankly weird constraint since these types have nothing in common.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-only-integers

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is not _exactly_ what you want, but you might come close by constraining to `IComparable`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I'm using a generic extension method using the typedescriptor class to convert objects, hence the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing matching exactly what you want, but `IConvertible` might do - it contains methods to convert a value to all the 'core' types, including `string`, and is implemented by all the core types you mention.

The BCL documentation recommends that you don't use this type directly, but instead use `Convert.ChangeType` or one of the `Convert.ToXXX` methods as required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe structure will give you all of the types you are looking for sans string.  It will also allow any that have been defined though, which is a problem you will have with any solution for this.

Honestly though this seems like its probably over engineering.  You should consider your requirements again and see if this is actually needed.