# Check template type and perform respective computation

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Generic class to handle float and doubles. I need to perform computation according to the type of the variable (float or double), but I am not sure whether the following implementation is the right way to do it. Need some suggestions on it.

```
// computeFloat is a method of some other class which actually computes and returns a float value
float computeFloat()
{
   float a;
   .... 
   return a; 
}

// setFloat is a method of some other class which actually sets a float value
void setFloat(float val)
{
  .....
}

TestClass<T> : IDisposable
{

public void getValue(ref T val)
{
   if(val is float)
   {
      object retVal = computeFloat();
      val = (float)retVal;
   }
   else
   { 
       throw new Exception(" Not implemented");
   }
}

public void setValue(T val)
{
   if(val is float)
   {
      object obj = val as object;
      float retVal = (float)obj;

       setFloat(retVal);
   }
   else
   { 
       throw new Exception(" Not implemented");
   }

}   

}
```

Comment: Consider checking Mark Gravell's http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html... (linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-only-integers)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the following to avoid if statements. You can also consider adding filters on the class to limit it to certain types.

```
public void getValue(ref T val)
{
   object retVal = compute<T>();
   val = (T)retVal;
}
```

Comment: What about the setValue method. Does it seems right to you.

Comment: I would do something similar there as well to avoid the hard coded type checks