# C# interface to check type T has an operator / A way to check if type T has an operator

Tags: c#, interface

```
interface IMathable
{
    public static IMathable operator +(IMathable l, IMathable r);
    public static IMathable operator -(IMathable l, IMathable r);
}
```

Is such possible? I have range of mathmatical class. Vector2/3/4/5/6 Matrix3x3/4x4/5x5/6x6 and so on.

They don't have a common class that they drive from. But they all have operators such as + - * /

I want to have a class like.

```
class MyClass <T> where T : IMathable
{
    T magnitude_required_to_reach_toHere;

    public MyClass (IMathable from, IMathable toHere)
        {
            magnitude_required_to_reach_toHere = from + toHere;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I was advised to have all my math classes to drive from abstract class but I can't have abstract class for all these mathmatical classes since they are built in, part of library; I can't fix the code.

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types Take a look at my answer, I think it might be your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot define operators on an interface.

But operators are more or less syntactical sugar.

You could define:

```
interface IMathable {

    IMathable add (IMathable other);
    IMathable sub (IMathable other);

}
```

In fact an operator is more or less a method, but where the identifier of that method (the `+` and `-`) and where the compiler maintains a symbol table and finds out the appropriate operator itself.

---

**Edit**: What you ask is not possible. Especially since an `IMathable` can't know what the supposed return type should be.

There is however some kind of workaround to solve it by using some functional programming:

```
class MyClass <T> {

    T magnitude_required_to_reach_toHere;

    public MyClass (T from, T toHere, Func<T,T,T> addfunction) {
            magnitude_required_to_reach_toHere = addFunction(from,toHere);
        }
}
```

Thus you pass a function as argument that must have the computational knowledge on how to solve the problem. For instance if `T` is an integer:

```
 MyClass<int> mc = new MyClass<int>(5,7,(x,y) => x+y);
```

Comment: but these classes are built in, part of lib, and I can't have them to have the interface "IMathable"

Comment: Do they inherit from `IMathable`?

Comment: Is the proposed functional programming a solution?

Comment: Thank you for clearing my curiosity. And your solution seems quite mind bending yet I find it too burdening for, supposedly a simple task. I wish I could do something like obj.GetType().GetOperator("+"); Thank you.