# Phantom generic constraints in C#

Tags: c#, generics, phantom-types

I came across this problematic quite often: I like to overload some method with same parameters for different return types, but .NET refuses generic constraints to sealed classes/primitives. I'll refer to this pattern as [`phantom generics`](http://rustbyexample.com/generics/phantom.html).

I know an ugly workaround: Putting every single interface the type implements behind the `where` statement.

My Question: **Is there any way to use explicit types in generics to illustrate the return type and keep methods distinct?**

Here is my code:

```
public static class Reinterpret {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe float Cast<T>(int value) where T : float { //'float' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
        return *((float*)&value); //reinterpret the bytes of 'value' to a float
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe float Cast<T>(uint value) where T : float { //'float' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
        return *((float*)&value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe double Cast<T>(long value) where T : double { //'double' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
        return *((double*)&value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe double Cast<T>(ulong value) where T : double { //'double' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
        return *((double*)&value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve here, to be honest. It looks like you'd be a lot better off just giving your methods different names.

Comment: Hi there, it's you again! And I guess you voted my question down... And no, renaming is not the preferred option, as I like to implement a c-style `reinterpret_cast` in C#.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't realize just who Jon Skeet is - the last time Jon Skeet was wrong on a C# question I hadn't even learned the language yet. Heeding his advice ia one of the best ways to become a better C# programmer.

Comment: No, I didn't vote it down - and while *you* may not prefer different names, I know that I (as a method consumer) would. Trying to port one idiom to another platform is often a bad idea, IME. That's not to say it's not fun to try odd things, but for production code I'd really try to steer away from this.

Comment: I find this interesting, but it is indeed unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What can I do to improve to clearify the matter, then?

Comment: What is the purpose of the generics when they're never referenced in the method itself other than the generic type specifier?  Have you checked out `Convert.ToDouble` and `Convert.ToSingle`?

Comment: As I wrote, the generic constraints fungate as return type indicator and keeps the methods distinct.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Jon Skeet is never wrong, when someone/something disagrees, the universe alters so it matches what he said :)

Comment: You're a fool to believe in god - I believe in codez

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types/22425077#22425077

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting to read!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics are not templates.  They do not act like templates.  They cannot be made to act like templates.

A "phantom" generic parameter is not going to help you simulate templates (and `reinterpret_cast` is not an actual template, anyway), because you soon are going to run into the fact that **generics do not support specialization**.

In particular, you asked "Is there any way to use explicit types in generics to ... keep methods distinct?" and commented that "the generic constraints ... keeps [sic] the methods distinct".  But they actually do not.  These methods are distinct only because the argument types are different.  Generics are computed from overloads, they do not influence overloading.

Comment: That's too bad :-( I wish the compiler would be a bit more intelligent at this point.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one *slightly* different way of approach it:

```
// Constraints just to be vaguely reasonable.
public static class Reinterpret<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    public T Cast(int value) { ... }
    public T Cast(uint value) { ... }
    public T Cast(float value) { ... }
    public T Cast(double value) { ... }
    // etc       
}
```

For the *implementation*, you could just have a `Func<int, T>` field, a `Func<double, T>` field etc, and then have a big static constructor:

```
static Reinterpret()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        // Assign all the fields using lambda expressions for ints.
        // The actual assignment might be tricky, however - you may
        // need to resort to some ghastly casting, e.g.
        castDouble = (Func<double, T>)(Delegate)(Func<double, int>)
            x => *((double*)&value;
    }
    ....
}
```

Then for any type you didn't want to support, the fields would be null. Each `Cast` method would look like:

```
if (castIntMethod != null)
{
    return castInt(value);
}
throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
```

To be honest, this isn't something I'd really want to do. I'd generally just use `BitConverter`. But it's an *option*.

Comment: Pretty good answer. But in this specific case I like to write fast, low-level code with `inline`d methods. As beeing inlined, the generic constraints will only be known at *compile time* (see the rust article I mentioned in the article), plus I don't want any overhead here.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman: Then I strongly recommend you simply write the overloads you want, overload on *input* only and using names like `ToInt32`, `ToDouble` etc. No, it won't look like Rust, and it won't look like C - it'll look like C#, and be all the more appropriate in a C# codebase for it.