# C# how to overload operator + for universal class

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

```
public struct Vector3<T>
{
    private T X { get; set; }
    private T Y { get; set; }
    private T Z { get; set; }

    public Vector3(T x, T y, T z) : this()
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public static Vector3<T> operator +(Vector3<T> v1, Vector3<T> v2)
    {
        return new Vector3<int>(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y, v1.Z + v2.Z);
    }
}
```

Gives error: Cannot apply operator '+' to oparands of type 'T' and 'T'.

Please help resolve.

Comment: I'm sure you will find lots of answers if you type the error message in Google.

Comment: Look at what you're asking it to do: construct a generic method that can apply + to ANY TYPE.  Integers, Strings, GUIDs, System.Net.WebClient, anonymous classes, System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException .... ANY CLASS WHATSOEVER.  It's not possible.  You need to restrict T to some subset interface so that the compiler knows it implements the + operator.

Comment: There is plenty of good information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types (also not covering `dynamic` suggestion by Tigran).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome that limitation *on your own risk*, by changing templated private members of the class to `dynamic` type. 
Example:

```
public struct Vector3<T>
{
    private dynamic X { get; set; }
    private dynamic Y { get; set; }
    private dynamic Z { get; set; }
    ...
    ....
}
```

There is no way, unfortunately, in `C#` to restrict template parameter to numeric values (I guess it is what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: would it be possible for example to have an addition overload for joining two arrays? a={1,2} b ={3,4}. Then c= a+b