# Converting collection to different type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm converting collection of types to collection of wrapper types

```
var buying = ord.Buying == null ? null : ord.Buying.Any() ? ord.Buying.Select<PurchasedBox, XXX.PurchasedBox>(x => x).ToList()
            : new List<XXX.PurchasedBox>();
var trading = ord.Trading == null ? null : ord.Trading.Any() ? ord.Trading.Select<TradedBox, XXX.TradedBox>(x => x).ToList()
            : new List<XXX.TradedBox>();
```

and also dictionary

```
(Any and null check) foo.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (XXX.Summary)x.Value)
```

The types are converted using implicit conversion

```
implicit operator XXX.TradedBox(TradedBox box)
```

This pattern is repeated serval times, but I'm not sure if it's possible to write generic helper with implicit conversions e.g.

```
    public static List<TE> ConvertList<T, TE>(List<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            return null;
        // compilation error cannot convert expression
        return list.Any() ? list.Select<T, TE>(x => x).ToList() : new List<TE>();
    }
```

Comment: you can pass convertor  in helper like `public static List<T> ConvertList<T, TE>(List<T> list, Func<T,TE> convert)` and pass it to select, also as variant   `list.Select<T, TE>(x => (TE)x)` or `list.Cast<TE>()`

Comment: (to original method in the post) I'm pretty sure you can't write just generic method as there is no way to have generic restriction for "T where has implicit cast operator"... Maybe questions about dealing with lack of generic restrictions for `operator +` may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types (or @Grundy's creator function)

Comment: @Grundy Not sure how list.Cast<TE>() could work.

Comment: @lukas try about [_Cast_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) in msdn

Answer (score 1):

Try it, cast to dynamic type does the magic, but it's unsafe if you pass the wrong type (there is no constraint).

```
public static List<TE> ConvertList<T, TE>(List<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
        return null;

    return list.Any() ? list.Select<T, TE>(x => (TE)(dynamic)x).ToList() : new List<TE>();
}
```

**NOTE**:
I've made the performance test, and it's right that using dynamic cost 3 times longer than using Func, or normal way (for this test).

```
public static List<TE> ConvertList<T, TE>(List<T> list)
    {
        return list.Any() ? list.Select<T, TE>(x => (TE)(dynamic)x).ToList() : new List<TE>();

    }
    public static List<Link> ConvertList1(List<LinkEntity> list)
    {
        return list.Any() ? list.Select<LinkEntity,Link>(x => x).ToList() : new List<Link>();

    }

    public static List<TE> ConvertList3<T, TE>(List<T> list,Func<T,TE> fuc)
    {
        return list.Any() ? list.Select<T, TE>(x => fuc(x)).ToList() : new List<TE>();

    }
```

The main:

```
var s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var a1 = Enumerable.Repeat(new LinkEntity { A = 10 }, 10000).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var b1 = ConvertList<LinkEntity, Link>(a1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var a2 = Enumerable.Repeat(new LinkEntity { A = 10 }, 10000).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var b2 = ConvertList1(a2);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var s3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var a3 = Enumerable.Repeat(new LinkEntity { A = 10 }, 10000).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var b3 = ConvertList3(a3, f => f);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Result:
**11609**
**4168**
**4611**

Comment: You also need : (dynamic)new List<TE>(); but that comes with performance penalty

Comment: @lukas, why do we need (dynamic) new List<TE>?, which `new List<TE>` matches with return type

Comment: sorry typo..... return list.Any() ? list.Select(x => (TE)(dynamic)x).ToList() : new List<TE>(); Compiler can infer params

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried running each method once before the stopwatch to "preheat" Jitter?

Comment: I've tried it, and result is the same ! 11669
  4266
  4737

Comment: also you are measuring the allocation. move a1, a2, a3 outside start and stop

Comment: yeah, the above result, allocation a1,a2,a3 are outside of measurement, but those 3 allocation time should be the same.