# Restrict generic T to specific types

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following method:

```
public static IResult<T, String> Validate<T>(this T value) {
} // Validate
```

How can I restrict T to be Int16, Int32, Int64, Double and String?

Comment: Probably by creating a non-generic method with 5 overloads for those types.  There's no way of restricting a generic method that specifically at compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't restrict generics in that way, you can only choose a single class as a constraint. You must either make 5 overloads or find a interface all 5 of those things share and use that. Which option you choose will depend on what `Validate` doe.

Here is how you would do the overloads.

```
public static IResult<Int16, String> Validate<T>(this Int16 value) {
} // Validate

public static IResult<Int32, String> Validate<T>(this Int32 value) {
} // Validate

public static IResult<Int64, String> Validate<T>(this Int64 value) {
} // Validate

public static IResult<double, String> Validate<T>(this double value) {
} // Validate

public static IResult<String, String> Validate<T>(this String value) {
} // Validate
```

Here is by using a common interface, all of the members you list Implement [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) so you could restrict by that, however this will allow any IConvertible not just the 5 you listed.

```
public static IResult<T, String> Validate<T>(this T value) where IConvertible {
} // Validate
```

Answer (score 11):

You can only do this:

```
public static IResult<T, String> Validate<T>(this T value) where T: int
{
    //validate
}
```

Only classes and interfaces can be used as constraint.

Comment: In which case, Generics add no benefit here since you can't derive something from int

Answer (score 6):

Constraining a generic to a set of specific types is not available. But [other types of constraints are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). The closest you can get with generics to what you want to achieve is to add the following constraints:

```csharp
public static IResult<T, String> Validate<T>(this T value) 
    where T : IConvertible, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    // Validate
}
```

All the primitive types implement these interfaces. To further restrict, the only option is to check the type at runtime and throw an exception if it doesn't match:

```csharp
Type type = typeof(T);
if (type != typeof(Int16) &&
    type != typeof(Int32) &&
    type != typeof(Int64) &&
    type != typeof(Double) &&
    type != typeof(String))
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

---

This isn't the nicest solution, but at least it will give you a bit of compile time and runtime safety.