# Add param of types in function, with condition of implementation for the types

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, parameters

I would like to write a function with some tricky input arguments :
This would be a param of types, and those type should implement a specific interface.
So the signature  would look like :

```
function void myFunction(string t,params Type[] types) where types:IMyInterface
```

Of course, it doesn't work like that.

Please don't suggest Generic Types, I expect several types, and I don't know how many.

Comment: (string t,params IMyInterface[] types)

Comment: That's why interfaces where invented

Comment: @MajkeloDev That's not it.

Comment: What do You mean ? As far as I understand he want to accept Items which Implement IMyInterface interface. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you have an upper limit on the number of params? Can there be more than, say, ten of them?

Comment: @MajkeloDev He wants to accept `System.Type` objects which *represent* types derived from `IMyInterface`, not *instances* of `IMyInterface`.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types?rq=1

Comment: It don't think it's possible. He can check in method if all the Types implements this inreface and Throw some exception if not

Comment: @MajkeloDev It's possible, but it's limited, and it does not look pretty (see below).

Comment: Aseem : You question is about numeric interface. Mine is on my own interface, nothing to do.
dasblinkenlight : No limit. I want to develop a framework, so the more flexible as possible.
MajkeloDev : Your last solution could work (I still need to do a cast later), but as noticed, this is really not pretty!

Comment: @Hermios A great deal of very useful frameworks put a limit on the number of types. Take a look at `System.Func<...>` group of delegates, they are limited to 16 type parameters. The limit used to be four in .NET 3.5, and the framework was still pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the compiler to do the compile-time check for you without using generics. Since generics do not provide variadic syntax for dealing with this kind of type parameter lists, a common workaround is to provide multiple overloads of a generic with different number of type parameters, and then call a common implementation:

```
void myFunction(string t) {
    myFunctionImpl(t, new Type[0]);
}
void myFunction<T0>(string t) where T0:IMyInterface {
    myFunctionImpl(t, new[] { typeof(T0) });
}
void myFunction<T0,T1>(string t) where T0:IMyInterface,
                                       T1:IMyInterface {
    myFunctionImpl(t, new[] { typeof(T0), typeof(T1) });
}
...
void myFunction<T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>(string t)
    where T0:IMyInterface,
          T1:IMyInterface,
          T2:IMyInterface,
          T3:IMyInterface,
          T4:IMyInterface,
          T5:IMyInterface,
          T6:IMyInterface,
          T7:IMyInterface,
          T8:IMyInterface,
          T9:IMyInterface {
    myFunctionImpl(t, new[] { typeof(T0), typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9) });
}
```

This approach lets you call `myFunction` with up to ten type parameters as needed.

Comment: no way that I do that. This is just awful. Besides, I have no limit for my types

Comment: @Hermios You are out of luck then: do the type checking at runtime.