# Generic Extension with less arguments than parameters

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I stumbled with this issue, if I define a class

```
class MyClass<T,U> {
    internal T myEement {get;set;}

    public MyClass(T Element) {
        myEement = Element;
    }
}
```

And declare extensions.

```
static class MyClassExtension{


    //What I want to do
    public static void nonWorkingExtension<P,T,U>(this P p, U u) where P:MyClass<T,U>
    {
        T Element = p.myEement;
        //Do something with u and p.Element
    }

    //What I have to do
    public static void workingExtension<P, T, U>(this P p, T dummy, U u) where P : MyClass<T, U>
    {
        T Element = p.myEement;
        //Do something with u and p.Element
    }

}
```

When calling them:

```
MyClass<int, double> oClass = new MyClass<int, double>(3);

oClass.workingExtension(0,0.3); //I can call this one.
oClass.nonWorkingExtension(0.3); //I can't call this.
```

It exits with error.

> Error 1   'MyClass' does not contain a definition for
>   'doSomething' and no extension method 'doSomething' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'MyClass' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

After testing I found that the extension **must** use each generic parameter in a function attribute.

Why is this?

Are there any work arounds?

---

CONTEXT

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834066/1477064) I was able to implement constrains on generic classes (to make them behave like C++ template specialisation). The solution uses extensions constrains to produce compile time errors on non implemented specialisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use each generic parameter. Your `nonWorkingExtension()` must work. I'm pretty sure that the error you're getting is not related to the code you've posted.

Anyway, back to the question. You don't need to use any generic constrains in this code, just use `MyClass<T, U>` instead:

```
static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static void nonWorkingExtension<T, U>(this MyClass<T, U> p, U u)
    {
        T Element = p.myEement;
        //Do something with u and p.Element
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I posted crashes on ` nonWorkingExtensions()`. Anyway, I'll check if your suggestion doesn't crash too.

Comment: @xvan What do you mean by "crashes"? It doesn't compile or what?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it doesn't compile.

Comment: removing `P` fixes the parameter issue, but I need to keep it to apply specialisation constrains. I tried wrapping `workingExtension()`  with the dummy parameter inside your code but it can't find the Extension (the same happens trying to call `workingExtension()` from inside `MyClass`)

Comment: @xvan That is weird as I can't imagine any reason to put constraints on `P` of an extension method. Anyway, if you want to it this way, you will need to specify the type arguments explicitly every time you call the method. Like this: `oClass.nonWorkingExtension<MyClass<int, double>, int, double>(0.3);`

Comment: Look's like *not possible* is the answer to my question. Tried with a wrapping `public static void workingExtension<P, T, U>(this P p, T dummy, U u) where P : MyClass<T, U>, SomePolicy<T,U>` inside `nonWorkingExtension<T, U>(this MyClass<T, U> p, U u)` where `MyClass<T,U>` is a `SomePolicy<T,U>`, but .net can't resolve P to SomePolicy.

Comment: @xvan It is possible, I've just tried both solutions with an online IDE (mono compiler, but it must work with roslyn as well)

Comment: Opened a follow up for my issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048248/implementing-multiparameter-c-template-like-behaviour-on-c-sharp-using-policy