# How to make extension for all at once ?

Tags: c#

I have to make extensions for all types arrays of numbers : ints, longs, floats, doubles, etc. that can do some things.
Of course, I could  do it for every type of integers, but that would look ugly.

```
double GetSomeValue (int[] array)
{
// some code
}

double GetSomeValue (double[] array)
{
// some code
}
etc, etc...
```

Is there any nice way to make in a short manner ?

Comment: have you considered generics? please post what you are going to be doing in the methods.

Comment: Specify *what* the methods shall *specifically* do.

Comment: Most probably the answer is no. There isn't a particularly useful generic constraint that would cover these types. (I'm assuming that you're trying to get the average value of the values in the array or something similar.)

Comment: I have to calculate different kind statistical values, e.g. standard deviation.

Comment: @Imugi Unfortunately, generics are essentially out of the question because these types don't share any common interface that would enable you to perform the necessary operations to calculate standard deviation (and C# doesn't support "or" in the constraints). T4 templates are a good compromise (see the answer). Using the `dynamic` keyword is also another compromise you can use to avoid code duplication, but it will have a runtime performance impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no. Depending on what you are actually trying to do you can use [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) method declaration but it will accept broader set of types, cause there is no way to restrict generic method to accept only numeric types in C#.

Also an option would be using [T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425077/2501279)

Comment: wow, T4 is great ! Haven't heard about it before, thanks!