# pass a generic type to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a generic function that passes a generic parameter to a function that has several overloads. The C++ equivalent would be [this](https://ideone.com/3OsmvD). Here is what I tried:

```
public void setUniform1<T>(int loc, T value) {
    GL.Uniform1(loc, value);
}
```

However this gives me the error

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'T' to 'double'

`GL.Uniform1` takes several types for the value paramter and I guess double is the first overload, that's why it's trying to convert to double.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Try `((dynamic)GL).Uniform1(loc, value);`

Comment: @YacoubMassad: This gives me the error: `error CS0119: 'GL' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`. I guess GL is not a namespace but a static class.

Comment: try `GL.Uniform1(loc,(double)(object)value)`

Comment: Please provide all the overloads for `GL.Uniform1`

Comment: @gartenriese, I though that `GL` is a variable. It seems its is a class and `Uniform1` is a static method.

Comment: @esiprogrammer: value is not necessarily double.

Comment: @DavidPine: It has overloads for int, float and double, I think.

Comment: What if `setUniform1` is called passing a string?

Comment: @codroipo: It will throw an exception, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36176835/2102827).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ templates and .NET generics only look the same, but behave differently: .NET generics need to be resolvable completely at compile time. In your example, that is not possible.

You can achieve a similar result to C++ templates with the `dynamic` keyword:

```
public void setUniform1<T>(int loc, T value) {
    GL.Uniform1(loc, (dynamic)value);
}
```

This will defer the overload resolution to the runtime at which point the type of `value` is actually known.
But, this has the issue that it will throw an exception if there is no overload of `GL.Uniform1` for the type of `value`.
Still, I have used this exact approach a couple of times. It makes sense when you can be certain that you will receive only a certain set of types and have overloads for all of them.
Another solution to avoid the runtime exception would be to provide an overload that takes `object` and performs a default action.

Comment: The `dynamic` keyword is risky and can cause runtime errors. If something other than a type that the `GL.Uniform1` accepts is passed in it will throw.

Comment: @DavidPine: Yeah, that's why I explained the pitfalls below the code.

Comment: Could you expand on "Another solution to avoid the runtime exception would be to provide an overload that takes object and performs a default action."?

Comment: @gartenriese What I meant by that is to have a `GL.Uniform1(int, object)`

Comment: Downvoter, if you don't leave a comment, I can't improve my answer. Please leave your feedback, thanks.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Ah, okay. It's in a external library, so I don't think that's possible. It's just a private project of mine so I guess carefully using `dynamic` is okay.

Comment: @gartenriese In that case I would agree, yes

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should pass a double instead, since that's what your function needs.

```
  public void setUniform1(int loc, double value) 
  {
      GL.Uniform1(loc, value);
  }
```

Generic types are only useful when you don't need a specific datatype, but in this case you do.

---

C# does not have a [numeric generic type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types).

Given that there are several versions of GL.Uniform, each of which takes a specific datatype, normally you would need three versions of the function.

However, since both float and int can be converted to a double without loss of precision, you could probably get away with just one function (taking a double).

```
  int    i;
  float  f;
  double d;

  setUniform1(loc, i);   // implicit conversion int   => double
  setUniform1(loc, f);   // implicit conversion float => double
  setUniform1(loc, d);
```

See [Implicit Numeric Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).

Comment: No, GL.Uniform1 can also take a float or an int, not only a double. If it would only take a double I would not need a generic method.

Comment: @gartenriese I am not sure that you actually need a generic method. You might be biased by your C++ background and their templates. How  are you actually calling `setUniform1`? Where are the values coming from that you pass?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I want to call `setUniform1` with either int, float, or double. There will also be a `setUniform2` which will take other types and call GL.Uniform2. I thought it could save me from copying and pasting all methods for each type.