# List of DTO with Dynamic type of propertie

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a Dto like this:

```
public class GroupEventualityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    public int IdEventuality { get; set; }
    public ???? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the propertie `Value` its a dynamic type (only decimal, string or int). My achieve its adding a `List<GroupEventualityDto>` where the `GroupEventualityDto` have a type of data decimal, int or another case type of that.
How to achieve that?

Comment: Make the class generic?

Comment: The list would end up as a generic: `List<GroupEventualityDto<T>>`. The actual usage would be: `List<GroupEventualityDto<decimal>>` OR `List<GroupEventualityDto<string>>` OR whatever type you want the DTO list to contain.

Comment: @Simon Restrepo - is `Value` property suppose to have the same type across all the elements of a list (for a specific date fetch or data persistence)? Do you persist list of `GroupEventualityDto` into a database?

Comment: You may want to use `object` for ???? and then cast on read operations. This will archive the goal but lose all the compile-time type safety. Dale's answer is much better from that point yet require more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to use a base class then inherit this base class and make this derived class generic like so:

```
public abstract class GroupEventualityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    public int IdEventuality { get; set; }
}

public class GroupEventualityDto<T> : GroupEventualityDto
{

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var one = new GroupEventualityDto<int>() {Value = 123};
    var two = new GroupEventualityDto<string>() {Value = "string"};
    var three = new GroupEventualityDto<double>() {Value = 45.54};

    var list = new List<GroupEventualityDto>()
    {
        one,
        two,
        three
    };

    foreach (var val in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val.GetType());
    }
}
```

You will have to deal with casting them back though when you want to get it out of the list.

Comment: This what I want, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why just not a generic type like this ?

```
public class GroupEventualityDto<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    public int IdEventuality { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you create a list of generic types where the type isn't the same, without using a base class or interface?

Comment: But, How do I add `GroupEventualityDto` to a List<GroupEventualityDto> with T??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to have a generic class but also want to restrict the type of the *Value* to specific types.

### Working but rather ugly generic type restriction

```
public class GroupEventualityDto<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    public int IdEventuality { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public GroupEventualityDto(){
        if(!(Value is int || Value is decimal || Value is string)) throw new ArgumentException("The GroupEventualityDto generic type must be either an int, decimal or string");
    }
}
```

In my second attempt I'll just check the type of Value to be one of the intended types and throw an ArgumentException if this is not the case.

Now, when I use

```
GroupEventualityDto<int> testTrue = new GroupEventualityDto<int>();
```

everything will just work the way I think the question is meant to implement this class.

If I'm trying to use a type which shouldn't work for that class as in

```
GroupEventualityDto<float> testFalse = new GroupEventualityDto<float>();


// System.ArgumentException: The GroupEventualityDto generic type must be either an int, decimal or string
```

the above exception will be thrown just like expected.

You can [try out the working code here](https://tio.run/##fZHNasMwEITP8VNsc7KhfQK3gULT0kOhUNNL6UGxN7ZAlox2ldQkfnZX/sE0xc7FIO/szKdRSnepsdi2jqTO4aMmxjIOUiWI4N2a3IoSTsGKWLBM4WBkBm9C6pDY@oWvbxA2p6iTrF6scdX2gJqdUJLrJzb3UvMGGIkT6xAeQOMRlnRhFC@47JURo8@zUHTNaJD2Vk3QBEHldsqDDxeaW0g2gYcfZR4DXjM4QY4cA3Wf5t@w97iq@BOwoEvgUyjfx@V0Gs9ghlHXsNyHN@GwKqlPO59hOmeYylKoi3/DM0URcGHNsW/t0eau9N7bnxQrlkaH66TAuVBPp9F6IK4rhNIRww4BJRdoQegO4HZKNXYMW4/dt@0v). I hope this approach might help you!

That being said, it could probably be done a tad more readable and enhance usability if the types were stored in an array of valid types but I couldn't wrap my head around that, unfortunately.

---

### Type constraints - which won't work here

At first glance, I would have thought using type constraints like in

```
public class GroupEventualityDto<T> where T: int, decimal, string
```

would work. However, it turns out that this does not work.

> 'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be
>   an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

A closely related question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types) already and it turns out that type constraints can't be restricted with a constraint in that case.

Comment: Thatk you for your anwers, I'll consider all.