# How would I constrain a generic method in C# to only allow T where T has TryParse?

Tags: c#, generics

```csharp
public int DoSomething<T>(string someString)
```

I want to insist that I can call `TryParse` on T. Is it possible to restrict T in that way? `TryParse` is not part of an interface, it just seems to exist on a number of value types, so how would I do this?

Comment: That's duck typing. C# doesn't have that, except for some early weirdness with enumerables (and still some with awaitables) -- no custom duck typing, in any case.

Comment: How would this work anyway, even if it was possible? `TryParse()` is a static method, so what object would you pass?

Comment: You can't do this statically but you could add a parameter for a `TryParse` delegate and pass it explicitly i.e. `DoSomething<double>("someString", double.TryParse);`

Comment: Maybe somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32664/579895

Comment: On a related note, C# does have the general notion of "objects that can convert themselves", in the form of `IConvertible`, which is in turn used by `Convert`. This setup is not particularly efficient, and it won't allow you to constrain types to *just* the ones parseable as strings, nor is it even a guarantee that the object can convert itself from a string, and to top it all off there's no `Convert.TryChangeType` -- but it's something. I'd personally prefer the delegate approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You cannot

Sorry. I don't know what else to say. It's simply not possible. You could allow any `T` and then do reflection somewhere and `throw` if it does not have a method called `TryParse` but as it's not part of an interface or base class... there is no way.

Comment: "Sorry. I don't know what else to say." You and me both. I was anxious that my question was too short.