# C# generics limited to a certain functions overloads

Tags: c#, generics

I am using a method from an external library, with the following prototypes:

```
void ReadRaster(byte[] vals);
void ReadRaster(float[] vals);
void ReadRaster(int[] vals);
```

In order to interface with that function, I was thinking on implementing a generic method such as

```
void OpenImage<PixelType>(int x, int y) {

    // Lots of code
    (...)

    var pixels = new PixelType[x * y];
    ReadRaster(pixels);

    // More code
    (...)
}
```

However, this won't do because I would have to limit `PixelType` to `int`, `float` or `byte`.

How could I do this?

Comment: How does PixelType become `byte[]`, `float[]` or `int[]`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types

Comment: In short - you can't.

Comment: why closed as duplicate? I was going to answer... ok the key is you have to share your _lots of code_ among 3 overloads using a method. you can also use enum of members `IntType, FloatType, ByteType` and with strategy pattern do your logic with minimum code

Comment: Imagine if it was the other way around - and the external library would have `ReadRaster()` methods for arrays of _all_ types - it still would not compile as `ReadRaster()` is not a generic method and the correct overload needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary If you have an answer, answer the duplicate, and not this one.

Comment: This is a terrific solution, which you can use even with lots of shared code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425077/993547.