# C# Create a Generic method contains generic collection and invoke Sum()

Tags: c#, linq, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Fun<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        // The foreach works
        foreach(T i in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        //The following line has error: List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'
        Console.WriteLine(list.Sum());
    }

     public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
        Fun<int>(arr.ToList());
    }
}
```

the `foreach` works, but `list.Sum()` doesn't. It shows:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best
>   extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

if I declare as `public static void Fun(List<int> list)`, then it works, anybody know why?

a similar C++ version can work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct MyList
{
    MyList(vector<T> v) : m(v){};
    vector<T> m;
    T Sum()
    {
        T sum = T();
        for(auto i : m)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};



template<class T>
void Fun(MyList<T> list)
{
    cout << list.Sum() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Fun(MyList<int>({1,2,3}));
    Fun(MyList<double>({1.0,2.0,3.0}));
}

output: 
6
6.3
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `int total = list.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));`

Comment: You cant `Sum` a list of *generic* Cat

Comment: Possibly, duplicate of the next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types.

Comment: @viveknuna Unless OP wants to sum non-integer types (float, double, decimal, etc.).

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you,  I could have posted, as it was not confirmed by OP and john has already answered the question with good explanation.

Comment: @viveknuna - `Convert.ToInt32(x)` - No!!! That's an awful way to do it.

Comment: Do keep in mind that LINQ already has `Aggregate` which does exactly what you want: `list.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y)`.

Comment: I want to Sum int,double etc. and also want to Average, I just don't understand why it cannot correctly find the overloaded Sum(IEnumerable<Int32>) or Sum(IEnumerable<double>) or Average(IEnumerable<Int32>) or Average(IEnumerable<double>)

Comment: Your C++ example works because `MyList<T>` defines `Sum`. `List<T>` in C# does not define `Sum`. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and there are `Sum` [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for specific closed types of `IEnumerable<T>`, as I discussed in my answer. Is there still an outstanding question that you need answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, how C++ works in this case, but in your code generic type parameter `T`  isn't constrained to any type and compiler doesn't know whether `T` supports `+` operator or not. You can use `dynamic` keyword here to allow the compiler to determine the type in runtime

```cs
public static void Fun<T>(List<T> list)
{
    dynamic sum = default(T);
    foreach (T i in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        sum += (dynamic)i;
    }            

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Or just in one line `var sum = list.Aggregate((arg1, arg2) => (dynamic)arg1 + arg2);`

But you should be very careful with it. If you pass a type, which doesn't support or overload the `+`, you'll get an exception in runtime. You can apply generic constraint to `T` and allow it match only numeric types
`where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable` (it's quite long, but there is no generic constraint to match a numeric types in C# for now)

Comment: that is a good sample, I change the code and it works :
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)list).Sum());

Comment: code like this works:
list.Aggregate((sum,x)=>sum+=(dynamic)x)

Comment: I don't know, did I click by mistake? I cannot currently upvote.
and BTW, I found the (dynamic)list).Sum() cannot work, I think the extension method cannot be dynamically bind to the object, but the list.Aggregate((sum,x)=>sum+=(dynamic)x)  works.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your C++ code and C# code is that in your C++ code, your `MyList<T>` template explicitly defines a `Sum` method. In contrast, C#'s `List<T>` doesn't define a `Sum()` method. Rather, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and there are [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) in the `System.Linq` namespace to provide `Sum` functionality to certain closed types of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Referring to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1), you'll see that `Sum` (without a selector, so not something like `Sum(x => x.Value)`) is only defined for the following closed types:

- `IEnumerable<Single>`
- `IEnumerable<Int32>`
- `IEnumerable<Int64>`
- `IEnumerable<Double>`
- `IEnumerable<Decimal>`
- `IEnumerable<Nullable<Single>>`
- `IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>`
- `IEnumerable<Nullable<Int64>>`
- `IEnumerable<Nullable<Double>>`
- `IEnumerable<Nullable<Decimal>>`

Therefore, it is not a feature of `List<T>`, and there is now way for the compiler to verify at compile time that the `T` in `List<T>` will be one of these types.

Note that `long` is the same as `Int64`, `int` is the same as `Int32`, and `single` is the same as `float`.

You could possibly provide some kind of aggregation functionality with the aid of a delegate:

```
public static void Fun<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, T, T> sumDelegate)
{
    T sumValue = default(T);
    // The foreach works
    foreach(T i in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        sumValue = sumDelegate(sumValue, i);
    }

    //The following line has error: List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'
    Console.WriteLine(sumValue);
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
var arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
Fun<int>(arr.ToList(), (x, y) => x + y);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RGD30522)

Comment: Doesn't the generic like a template in C++? I thought it can deduce the T from "Fun<int>(arr.ToList());", and finally call Sum(IEnumerable<Int32>) ?

Comment: I'm not too sure about generics in C++, but C# is statically typed, which means the compiler will ensure type safety at compile time. Because the extension methods are defined for specific values of `T`, the compiler has no way of knowing that to do if you were to pass in a `T` of `string`, for example. There is no general `Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` method.

Comment: @xinglong - Since `T` is not constrained then the compiler can only deal with it as if it had the same properties and methods of `object`.

Comment: @xinglong - .NET does not compile generics like C++ templates nor like Java does it. The .NET's IL specifically understands generic types so it can create and compile the types at compile-time and doesn't need to make any run-time types - hence it can't do what you think it should.

Comment: ok, I added a sample C++ version, looks like in .Net do have different behavior from c++.

Comment: now I think  in .net, "T" looks like an interface,  and will only be resolved during runtime, but since the "T" interface doesn't support "+=" operator or Sum extension methods, so we cannot perform the "+=" like C++, in C++, the "T" is the complete type (int, long,double) during compiling, so it knows it suport "+=".  The solution should be like @Pavel Anikhouski :

Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)list).Sum());

that way the .net runtime will know if the list support Sum() or not.