# C# - Accept IEnumerable of any type as parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

i have this constructor which was supposed to accept any IEnumerable of any type, and try to convert the values to the desired type

```
public ChartData(IEnumerable<dynamic> labels, IEnumerable<dynamic> values)
            {
                this.values = values.Select(x=>(float)Convert.ToString(x));
                this.labels = labels.Select(x=>(string)Convert.ToString(x));
            }
```

when i call this constructor i can pass ienumerables of the type string, but not int or float
how can i make a constructor that will accept ienumerables of any type without making tons of overloads?

Comment: Types exist for compile time type checks. Dynamic - more so then even object - *turns off* compile time type checks. | Co- and Conravairance are a option. But usually you would make ChartData generic, so you can decide a type to put into the IEnumerable.

Comment: Look up Generic Methods on how to do this in a proper way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Comment: If you accept any type, that would also include `IEnumerable<User>` and ``IEnumerable<Car>`, how would you expect to convert them to float and string? It would be much better to have an object that encapsulates a float and a string value, use an interface for that.

Comment: Something to remember here is, thanks to localization/cultural concerns, converting values to and from strings is surprisingly slow and error-prone. It's something to avoid.
Therefore if we have, say, an `IEnumerable<double>`, and need to get it to `IEnumerable<float>`, converting each double to a string and then each of those strings back to a float is probably the slowest and least reliable possible way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the type use non-generic version `IEnumerable`(which is base interface for `IEnumerble<T>`):

```
public ChartData(IEnumerable labels, IEnumerable values)
{
      // x is of type Object for both lines.
      this.values = values.Select(x=>(float)Convert.ToSingle(x));
      this.labels = labels.Select(x=>(string)Convert.ToString(x));
}
```

Note that

- you lose all type safety - someone can easily pass list of files or some other random types as either of arguments
- in general generics version is preferable if you deal with value types due to boxing cost. Fortunately in your case you need boxed value anyway or `Convert`.

Personally I'd only accept `IEnumerable<float>` (or maybe `double`) and `IEnumerable<String>` as arguments - caller of this method will have more knowledge to pick desired fields/conversion than my code trying to guess the type they passed in. If some "any numeric type" would be a desired input I'd check [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types) and implement all variant instead of falling back to runtime reflection with `dynamic` or lack of type safety with non-generic version.

Comment: "Personally I'd only accept `IEnumerable<float>` and `IEnumerable<string>` as arguments". **EXACTLY**. The caller will know the types they have, and be in a better position to handle the conversions. The `Cast<>()` and `Select<>()` methods makes this easy for them. Round-tripping everything through `string` as in the question is the slowest and least reliable way to do this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn one problem with that is leaving it open to mismatched numbers of elements. 10 values and 11 labels for example.

Comment: @DavidG Oh, definitely. Matching collections based on index is rarely a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you accept any type, that would also include `IEnumerable<User>` and `IEnumerable<Car>`, how would you expect to convert them to float and string? It would be much better to have an object that encapsulates a float and a string value, use an interface for that. For example, have an interface like this:

```
public interface IChartItem
{
    float Value { get; set; }
    string Label { get; set; }
}
```

An example class:

```
public class Foo : IChartItem
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public float Value => (float)MyProperty;
    public string Label => Name;
}
```

And now your function could be generic with a constraint:

```
public void ChartData<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : IChartItem
{
    this.values = items.Select(x => x.Value);
    this.labels = items.Select(x => x.Label);
}
```

### Alternative Option

You could also pass in your object along with a couple of `Func` parameters to get the value and label. For example:

```
public void ChartData<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, 
    Func<T, float> valueSelector, 
    Func<T, string> labelSelector)
{
    this.values = items.Select(x => valueSelector(x));
    this.labels = items.Select(x => labelSelector(x));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ChartData(foos, f => (float)f.MyProperty, f => f.Name);
```