# Generic extension method for floating number?

Tags: c#, generics, rounding

In .Net 7, there is `IFloatingPoint`. I read the following code for .Net 6.
It uses `struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>`. Are all these constraint necessary?

Code:

```
using System;

namespace MyExtensions
{
    public static class NumericExtensions
    {
        public static T Round<T>(this T value, int decimalPlaces) where T : 
            struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
        {
            decimal decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
            decimal rounded = Math.Round(decimalValue, decimalPlaces);
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(rounded, typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) It certainly compiles and runs without the type constraints.  Necessary for what?  (2) It's already a garbage method that trashes large `double` values.  I don't see the merit in making this generic if it's just going to trash the data stored in the generic type.  Surely conceived of by a C++ programmer.

Comment: (1) Adding type constraint `struct` can prevent the method from being used as `"abc".Round(3)`. What's the purpose of adding `IFormattable, IConvertible`, etc? (this is not my code) (2) I don't want to write multiple functions for `float`, `double`, `decimal`, etc.

Comment: If you're looking for performance, a generic method isn't the way to do it. I would just get rid of the extension method and call `Math.Round()` where you need to.

Comment: What does this mean: _"The AI gave the following method"_?

Comment: Related:  [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32664/1563833)  And .NET 7's [IFloatingPoint<TSelf>.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ifloatingpoint-1.round?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-ifloatingpoint-1-round(-0))

Comment: There are already `Math.Round` overloads for `double` and `decimal`. What else do you want to round? If you need `float`, write a simply method that casts the float to double and casts the result back to a float. Your generic results in every call walking around the block before returning

Comment: _"the code is actually from chat GCP"_ - `posting code from ChatGPT is not allowed`.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy.   How do we know your code isn't being sourced from another's post on SO?  You don't even have a citation to ChatGPT in your post let alone to the ultimate author which for all we know is a ChatGPT-web-scanned e-book.

Comment: Re: ChatGPT.  That's pretty good code considering it was written by a computer that doesn't have a clue what it's doing.  Of course, it reads like it was written by someone (/something) that didn't have a clue what it was doing (and definitely not by a C++ programmer :-))

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, probably heat of the moment. ;)  _"ChatGP"_ - lolz agreed! :D

Comment: OK updated the question. It really is not that important where the code originally comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding only makes sense for floating point numbers. In C#, we only have three types of floating point numbers (`float`, `double`, `decimal`). The `Math.Round` methods exists in two variants, one for `double` and one for `decimal`. Both use different rounding algorithms internally. Using the rounding method for doubles on decimals or vice versa can lead to unexpected results.

Since we only have three relevant types, the simplest approach for generating extension methods is to write one for each type. One line is enough per type:

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{
    public static double Round(this double value, int decimalPlaces) => Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces);
    public static decimal Round(this decimal value, int decimalPlaces) => Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces);
    public static float Round(this float value, int decimalPlaces) => (float)Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces);
}
```

---

Starting with .NET 7, the numeric types in the framework were extended to implement generic interfaces that make it easier to write generic methods that deal with numbers. There is now also `Round()` methods on the floating point types themselves, so that we don't have to use `Math.Round()` anymore but can use the `Round()` method from the actual type.

With this new support, we can write a single extension method that supports all floating point types (also including the new `Half` type):

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{
    public static T Round<T>(this T value, int decimalPlaces) where T : IFloatingPoint<T> => T.Round(value, decimalPlaces);
}
```

---

- [Microsoft blog post on the new generic abilities of numeric types in .NET 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/)

Comment: I totally agree with the rounding approach you gave. And in .Net 7, `IFloatingPoint` is a perfect constraint for the generic. Let's assume we need a generic method for floating point method before .Net 7, is `struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>` the best try for `IFloatingPoint`?

Comment: Even with those restrictions, the extension method will be available for types like `int` and `DateTime` where rounding makes no sense. In older versions, there is no generic type restriction that will match floating point types but no other types.