# Make Abstract Property of Base Class Abstract in Inherited Class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract

I have an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    internal abstract string DatabaseTableName { get; }
    internal abstract string ObjectType { get; }
 
    // other class members not important
}
```

That has two abstract subclasses -- the only difference is one has a 32-bit Id and the other a 64-bit Id:

```
public abstract class BaseObject32 : BaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
 
    // other class members not important
}

public abstract class BaseObject64 : BaseObject
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    // other class members not important
}
```

I would like to make it so that any class that inherits BaseObject32 or BaseObject64 *must* implement these two properties, but then those properties should be accessible via the BaseObject class.

In other words, I'd like to do this:

```
public class Cat : BaseObject32 
{
    DataBaseTableName => "animals.cat";
    ObjectName => "Cat";
}
```

And then be able to do this:

```
BaseObject c = new Cat();
string x = c.DatabaseTableName;
```

I'm clearly missing something.  I've tried addding "new" and "override" within my Cat class, but it keeps saying I need to implement the inherited class member.  Here is a rough idea of what I want in each inheriting class.

```
private const string _ObjectType = "Cat";
private const string _DataBaseTableName = "animals.cat";

internal override string ObjectType => _ObjectType;
internal override string DatabaseTableName => _DataBaseTableName;
```

I am hopeful this is possible and I'm just missing something...

Comment: Do you mean you just need `internal override string DatabaseTableName => "animals.cat";`? I'm confused, since that seems to do exactly what you need. e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/EKIu1R

Comment: @DavidG - I tried that, but I get this:  CS0534 'Cat does not implement inherited abstract member ...

Comment: I just included a running example in my first comment

Comment: @DavidG -- that sure works on fiddle, but with the identical constructs I'm still getting that message.  Interestingly when I "implement abstract class" it creates the stubs but still gives me that error.  I'll study your example more -- it's exactly what I want but I'm not getting the same results.  I'm on Framework 4.8.  That shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Does it work with `internal override string DatabaseTableName { get { return "animals.cat"; } }`

Comment: Look at my answer again. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Final follow-up...  the issue for reasons completely unknown to me the program would not compile with the `internal` modifier.  I want these to be internal, not public.  However, when I changed the properties to `public` it compiles.  Wow, I'm confused.  Thanks to all who helped diagnose and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would simply do this:

```cs
public class Cat : BaseObject32
{
    internal override string DatabaseTableName => "animals.cat";
    internal override string ObjectType => "Cat";
}
```

However, since you are using an older version of C#, you may not be able to use a lamda expression for a property (i.e. [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)) so need to use the older syntax:

```cs
public class Cat : BaseObject32
{
    internal override string DatabaseTableName { get { return "animals.cat"; } }
    internal override string ObjectType { get { return "Cat"; } }
}
```

Comment: FYI Lambdas do work for properties in 4.8... okay, so I took this and put it into a clean project on 4.8, and it's working perfectly.  So something is amiss with my actual project, but clearly your suggestion works.  My initial error was I was referencing the two properties in BaseObject32 and BaseObject64, but I removed those and am still having issues.  Regardless, you have demonstrated a working solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Just use Generics:

```
public abstract class BaseObject<T> where T: struct 
{
    public abstract T Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string DatabaseTableName { get; }
    public abstract string ObjectType { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseObject32 : BaseObject<int>
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseObject64 : BaseObject<long>
{
    public override long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : BaseObject32
{
    public override string DatabaseTableName => "animals.cat";
    public override string ObjectType => "Cat";
}

BaseObject<int> c = new Cat();
string x = c.DatabaseTableName;
```

If you want to limit the constraint more precisely, see this topic too:
[Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types)

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure OP doesn't care about the Id property here anyway

Comment: Yeah, sorry...  the Id is not super relevant; it was only to illustrate why I have the abstract subclasses.  BaseObject has a lot of class members, and BaseObject32 and 64 basically only add this one property.

Comment: I added the 2 properties what you wanted.